# Bulk printer installation using powershell command not working

Tags: powershell, printing

I need to install 20+ printers and have the below details are with me, can somebody help me checking this script.

CSv content: 
PrinterName PortName    PrinterHostAddress  PrintDriverName

---

Script:

```
$PrinterList = IMPORT-CSV D:\csv\PrinterList.csv -Delimiter ';'

$portExists = Get-Printerport -Name $portname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if (-not $portExists) {

foreach ($printer in $PrinterList ) {
   Add-PrinterPort -name $portName -PrinterHostAddress $PrinterHostAddress
}
}

$printDriverExists = Get-PrinterDriver -name $printDriverName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($printDriverExists) {
foreach ($printer in $PrinterList) {
    Add-Printer -Shared -Name $PrinterName -PortName $portName -DriverName $printDriverName
}
}else{
    Write-Warning "Printer Driver not installed"
}
```

Comment: You import the csv, but neglect to use the values in there. By simply popping up with undefined variables like `$portname` and `$PrinterHostAddress` you are using `$null` values. Loop over the imported `$PrinterList` and use the values found in there as in `$_.portName` and `$_.PrinterHostAddress`. There are many.. MANY examples to be found on how to import a csv and iterate the values.

Comment: Hi Can you share some links, i am very new to powershell, also if you could suggest some edits to code.

Comment: Why not start with googling for "powershell iterate csv"